# Trigger CSS :hover only when hovering over border box

Tags: html, css

I am creating a rectangular outline with a `5px` thin border box around an empty `<div>`. When the user hovers over the border I want the border to change colour. That's all working fine, but I don't want the border to remain changed when the user's mouse is inside the `<div>` because it's no longer actually on the border.

See an example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/qbcc1trt/

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
.myborder {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.myborder:hover {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(100, 200, 100, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ff/00/5e/ff005e0fa600c51c5e36f6059bbe6053.jpg">
  <div class="myborder"></div>
</div>
```

Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without some JavaScript

Comment: How would it be accomplished with JS?

Comment: What if you built out a square using four elements and making them all trigger on hover w/CSS? I've never seen this type of action, do you have an example of it working elsewhere?

Comment: @abagshaw Do you really need shadow to be transparent? If not I have a solution.

Comment: Are you ok with different html structure?

Comment: I retract my "without js" comment. See my answer below.

Comment: @Linek yes I do need the shadow to be transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the answer has been marked as answered but I found a solution that doesn't use `calc` but `nth-child` instead which has better [compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) than [calc](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.myborder {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
}

.myborder div:nth-child(1) {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.myborder div:nth-child(1):hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(100, 200, 100, 0.6);
}

.myborder div:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ff/00/5e/ff005e0fa600c51c5e36f6059bbe6053.jpg">
  <div class="myborder">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - while this does look like a nicer solution I don't think it's going to work for my specific use case as I am going to need to change the colours of each box so I'm guessing `nth-child` isn't going to work.

Comment: @abagshaw You can use classes for inner divs to specify colors. `nth-child` is not ever required here.

Comment: Actually on second thoughts this might work - I'll give it a shot and report back.

Answer (score 6):

`:hover` events only work on the top most element (and the elements inside). So you can achieve this effect by making another div the same size as your `myborder` but subtracting the size of the border. Then place it directly above `myborder`.

This way, the hover event will trigger while over the border (box shadow in your case) but no the inside. See the demo below

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
.myborder {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.hover-cover {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(5% + 5px);
  left: calc(20% + 5px);
  box-shadow: none;
  z-index: 1;
  width: calc( 40% - 10px);
  height: calc( 50% - 10px);
}
 

.myborder:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(100, 200, 100, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ff/00/5e/ff005e0fa600c51c5e36f6059bbe6053.jpg">
  
  <div class="hover-cover"></div>
  <div class="myborder"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Linek true, but this functionality can be achieved without `calc`, I was just trying to maintain the original code as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks! That compatibility is fine for me. I was actually thinking about doing something like this. I'll give this a shot. The reason I didn't go with this idea before is I'm going to be dynamically creating a bunch of these rectangles and it seems a little bloated to be adding a second div to each box just to prevent the hover from triggering for each box - but hey it doesn't use JS so that's a plus

Comment: I think you could swap out the extra div for the `:before` attribute

Comment: Hmm..doesn't seem to be working with `:before`. Does it work for you?

Comment: @KevinJantzer actually I found a solution that doesn't use `calc` but `nth-child` instead which has better compatibility but uses 2 divs instead of 1.

Comment: @abagshaw – you're right, `:before` doesn't seem to work, probably because its inside the border element

Answer (score 1):

It's almost the same solution as the one provided by @Kevin:
https://jsfiddle.net/qbcc1trt/1/

The idea is to put two elements, one (B) above the other one (A), so when the user will `:hover` element B he will actually not `:hover` element A.
You need to make sure the element B is not inside element A

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
.borderContainer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
}
.myborder {
  content: '';
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 5px * 2);
  height: calc(100% - 5px * 2);
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.myborder:hover {
  content: '';
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(100, 200, 100, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ff/00/5e/ff005e0fa600c51c5e36f6059bbe6053.jpg">
<div class="borderContainer">
  <div class="myborder">
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Note the I used here a parent container (which might be easier, depending on your solution).